# validation does not work in popup form values in magento

Tags: magento

I am using Ajax for sending data on controller. Here I use TinyMCE editer in my popup form and I need to validate it. But here validation does not work properly in Magento.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should clarify more on this.

By the way wherever you have put your form in popup give it an ID like  and in your form if you have text boxes then put class 'required-entry' in all required textboxes and you should have one submit button.

Then finally put this script after form :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var popupForm = new VarienForm('popupform', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

See how it goes.